# PHP Sessions only working in parts of my code?

Tags: php, html, session

Im wondering why my sessions are not being set when they are in the "login()" function. If i set sessions in the constructor or in the find() function, they are properly set, but if i put them in the login() function, they are not being set. Can anyone answer me why? Session start() is being loaded in all files because of autload, so that shouldent be a problem.

login.php:

```
     <?php 
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
        require_once '/home/1/u/someplace/www/Core/init.php';
        if(Input::exists()){
        if(Token::validate(Input::get('token'))){

        $validate = new validator;
        $passed = $validate->validate($_POST, array('email' =>  array('required' => 'true'), 'password' => array('required' => 'true')));

        if ($passed) {

            $user = new users(Input::get('username'));

            if($user->login(Input::get('password')));{

                redirect::to("http://www.someplace.info/Includes/index.php");
            }


        }else{
            echo "not passed";
        }
    }
}
?>

<html>
    <header></header>
<body>

<form action="" method="post">
    <input name="username" value="<?php echo Input::get('email');?>">
    <input name="password" value="<?php echo Input::get('password')?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>" > 
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Users.php :

```
<?php
class users{

    private $_db;
    private $_data = array();
    private $_sessionName;
    private $_cookieName;
    private $_isLoggedIn;
    private $_link;

function __construct($user = null){
    $this->_db = Database::getDBI();
    $this->_cookieName = Config::get('cookie:cookie_name');
    $this->_sessionName = Config::get('session:session_name');

    if (Session::exists($this->_sessionName) && $user == null) {
        $user = Session::get($this->_sessionName); //session = name[user], value = user_id
        //sessions can be put here.
            if($this->find($user)){
                   $this->_isLoggedIn = true;

            } elseif(!$this->_link == "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]") {
                    redirect::to("http://www.ulrikbf.info/includes/login.php");
            }

    } else {
            $this->find($user);

        }
    }

    public function create($table,$field,$values = array()){
    if (!$this->_db->insert($table,$field,$values)) {
        return false;
        }

    }


public function find($user = null){
    //sessions can be put here.

    switch ($user) {
        case is_numeric($user):
                $this->_data = $this->_db->get('users', array('user_id','=',$user));
            break;
        case $user == null:
                $this->_data = $this->_db->get('users', array('email','=',session::get(config::get('session::session_name'))));
            break;
        default:
                $data = $this->_data = $this->_db->get('users', array('email','=', $user));
                $datafirst = $data->first();
                    if ($user == $datafirst->email) {
                    $this->_data = $datafirst;
                    }
            break;
            return $this->_data;
    }
}

public function login($user_password = null){

        $password = hash::make($user_password, $this->_data->salt);
        $passwordHash = $this->_data->password;

            if ($passwordHash == $password ) {

                $hashSession = hash::unique();

                    session::put('hash', $hashSession); //not working
                    session::put($this->_sessionName,$this->data()->user_id); //not working.

            $this->_db->insert('sessions','user_id, hash', array(
            $this->_data->user_id, $hashSession));

                return true;
            }
        return false;
    }

public function data(){
        return $this->_data;
    }

    public function isLoggedIn(){
        return $this->_isLoggedIn;
    }


}
```

index.php:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require_once '/home/1/u/someplace/www/Core/init.php';

$user = new users();
print_r($_SESSION);
if($user->isLoggedIn()){

echo "Great";

} else {

echo "Not so great";
}



?>
```

init.php:

```
session_start();

//Standard PHP Library(spl)..
spl_autoload_register(function($class)  {
        require_once '/home/1/u/someplace/www/Classes/' . $class . '.php';

});
```

session.php:

```
<?php
class session {
   public static function put($name,$value){
        return $_SESSION[$name] = $value;

    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide more details of the problem, and less details of the code: break the code down to the smallest example that you can test and still demonstrates your problem, then post that with a clear explanation of what you wanted to happen, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start session in each file

### session_start();